# Getting combinations of subtrings

Tags: java

Lets say I have a string = "hellomen".

Say I have a database and I could compare substring combinations of said string and could tell if substring is a valid word with a minimum of 3 letters. There should be no overlap or unused letters when checking.

Output:

1. hell, omen
2. hello, men

How do I get different combinations of the substrings to be able to check?

For example:

START

1st check:

hel, lomen
(returns fail, invalid words)

2nd check:

hell, omen
(returns success)

3rd check:

hello, men
(returns success)

4th check:

hellomen
(returns fail)

END

Comment: Look at the comma in your examples, and think about what index the comma is starting at and finishing at. Then use the `String.split()` method in an appropriate loop.

Comment: First come up with the pattern/idea, what you exactly want and which prerequisites apply to your problem [input pattern, output pattern], and then think about algorithm. At the first sight, you're not asking for something simple..

Comment: Could a big string be also split into more than 2 words?

Comment: Yes, it could be more than 2 words

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a very easy `for` loop through the string. If you know that a word is at least 3 characters long, then you can use something like the following.

```
int size = wordToCheck.length();
for (int i = 3; i + 3 < size; i++) {
    if (myDatabase.isValidWord(wordToCheck.substring(0, i) && 
myDatabase.isValidWord(wordToCheck.substring(i, size))) { // check against the database
        listOfGoodWords.add(wordToCheck.substring(0, i));
        listOfGoodWords.add(wordToCheck.substring(i, size)); // add to a list of successes
    }
}
```

Here, `wordToCheck.substring(0, i)` is the first part of your word, and `wordToCheck.substring(i, size)` is the second part. For `listOfGoodWords`, you could have any sort of data structure to keep your successful strings, like an `ArrayList<String>` or if you want to store the pairs together you could keep an `ArrayList<String[]>` where each element is an array of two strings, which is the successful pair, but in reality, this data structure could be whatever you want that works best for what you are trying to do.